# Angular5 - ngOnInit called every time a component is used on the page

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm just getting cookin' in the new angular styles and have found an issues I can't get around. I have made a component called `slider`. That slider is used 3 times on the page. The ngOnInit of the component is getting called 3 times which is causing some errors.

Should I rewrite this as a slider service? Is there a way to do this so that multiple instances of a component don't cause unwanted function calls.

Comment: The `ngOnInit` is supposed to initialize stuff for each particular instance of the component. Why not make use of the parent component, and pass over data to its children?

Comment: There really is no question here. You know the problem, and the solution. The `slider` component runs `ngOnInit` for every instance of the component. Do what @Jeto said, and just have whatever data in the parent component, or do what you said, and create a shared service so they share data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the component 3 times at the same page?

I suggest two solutions, first is to make parent component and pass the data to the children.
Second is to make inject `Input()` variable and in each call you can pass what you want like this:

```
<p>This is my page</p>
<app-slider [data]="one"></app-slider>
<app-slider [data]="two"></app-slider>
<app-slider [data]="three"></app-slider>
```

And in your `slider.ts` you can define the one two three

```
Input() one: any;
Input() two: any;
Input() three: any;
```